# Quantization of Onnx model

Tags: python, deep-learning, quantization, onnx, onnxruntime

I am trying to quantize an ONNX model using the onnxruntime [quantization tool](https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime/tree/e26e11b9f7f7b1d153d9ce2ac160cffb241e4ded/onnxruntime/python/tools/quantization).

My code is below for quantization:

```py
import onnx
from quantize import quantize, QuantizationMode

# Load the onnx model     
model = onnx.load('3ddfa_optimized_withoutflatten.onnx')

# Quantize
quantized_model = quantize(model, quantization_mode=QuantizationMode.IntegerOps)
 
# Save the quantized model
onnx.save(quantized_model, 'quantized_model.onnx')
```

After this method the model I am getting has 0 dimensional model. What arguments do I have to pass in quantize function so I can get a proper model?

Answer (score 2):

Unless you share the onnx model, it is hard to tell the cause.

For OnnxRuntime 1.4.0, you can try the following:

```
    quantized_model = quantize(onnx_opt_model,
                               quantization_mode=QuantizationMode.IntegerOps,
                               symmetric_weight=True,
                               force_fusions=True)
```

If the problem still exits, please share your onnx model so that we can take a look.

Comment: Hey after trying this, I am getting a quantized model with reduced size, but I was expecting to get improved inference timing, but there is no inference time improvement I got, so can you suggest me something on that aspect?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
def quantize_onnx_model(onnx_model_path, quantized_model_path):
    from onnxruntime.quantization import quantize_dynamic, QuantType
    import onnx
    onnx_opt_model = onnx.load(onnx_model_path)
    quantize_dynamic(onnx_model_path,
                     quantized_model_path,
                     weight_type=QuantType.QInt8)

    print(f"quantized model saved to:{quantized_model_path}")

quantize_onnx_model("/content/drive/MyDrive/Datasets/model.onnx", "/content/drive/MyDrive/Datasets/model_quant.onnx")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).